# How to save dynamic form in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I Have a for where you can add multiple lines by click on a button and I want to store the data into the database

This is the error I get when I submit the form - Array to string conversion

Form inputs I didn't post the form element since I don't think I needed to show it here.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" />
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link[]" />
```

Controller

```
public function help_store(Request $request)
{
    $helps = collect([]);
    if ($request->title) {
        foreach ($request->title as $key => $title) {
            $model = Help::updateOrCreate([
                'title' => $title
            ], [
                'link' => $request->link[$key]
            ]);
            $helps->push($model);
        }
    }
    Help::whereNotIn('id', $helps->pluck('id'))->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I see this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `helps` (`title`, `link`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, 2021-01-15 20:02:42, 2021-01-15 20:02:42))

Comment: I would suggest `print_r($request->title);` to see what you get back from the request input, the error would suggest there is a Not Null constraint on your database at column title, and there is an empty title in your array.

Comment: you are not getting title data for some of the field, you can either put a default value if no value is inserted, or put a validation that title is required